# Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am [switching](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties) from [MYSQL](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/resources/dbscript_mysql.sql) to [ORACLE](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/resources/dbscript_oracle.sql).

I have JPA Authentication setup like [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/java/com/contentplusplus/springboot/security/AppUserDetailsService.java):

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AppUser user = userRepository.findByUseremailIgnoreCase(email);
```

With MySQL all works fine. But for Oracle, during login using JPA authentication I am getting this exception.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`
```

Followed by these exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Any clue what I am missing and where to debug?

My table structure is as per below:

```
create table CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user (
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) NOT NULL,
useremail VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
userpassword VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
useruuid VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
userfirstname VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
userlastname VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
userenabled NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
created_by VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
created_date VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
modified_by VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
modified_date VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT appuser_pk PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (useremail, useruuid));

create table CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_role(
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT approle_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE (name));


CREATE TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_department (
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) NOT NULL,
departmentuuid VARCHAR(150),
departmentheadname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
departmentheademail varchar(255) NOT NULL,
departmentname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
userid NUMBER NOT NULL,
created_by VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
created_date VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
modified_by VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
modified_date VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT appdepartment_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE (departmentname, departmentuuid));

CREATE TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user_department (
userid NUMBER NOT NULL,
departmentid NUMBER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user_department ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AUSERDEPTUSERID FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES app_user (id);
ALTER TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user_department ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AUSERDEPTDEPTID FOREIGN KEY (departmentid) REFERENCES app_department (id); 
ALTER TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_department ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AUSERUSERID FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES app_user (id);

CREATE TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user_role (
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) NOT NULL,
userid NUMBER NOT NULL,
roleid NUMBER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT appuserrole_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));

ALTER TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user_role ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AURUSERID FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES app_user (id);
ALTER TABLE CONTENTPLUSPLUS.app_user_role ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AURROLEID FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES app_role (id);
```

Below is the query which gets fired during the login operation (shows up only for MySQL):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.id,
        a1_0.created_by,
        a1_0.created_date,
        a1_0.modified_by,
        a1_0.modified_date,
        a1_0.useremail,
        a1_0.userenabled,
        a1_0.userfirstname,
        a1_0.userlastname,
        a1_0.userpassword,
        a1_0.useruuid 
    from
        app_user a1_0 
    where
        upper(a1_0.useremail)=upper(?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        r1_0.userid,
        r1_1.id,
        r1_1.name 
    from
        app_user_role r1_0 
    join
        app_role r1_1 
            on r1_1.id=r1_0.roleid 
    where
        r1_0.userid=?
```

Comment: Without the query, it's difficult to help you but first usual suspect to come in mind in converted code is the usage of implicit conversion not working the same in all RDMS... (there is an AskTom - SQL Office Hours - session about date/time with the code here https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_OM0SXI26XDU8JOG6XHDE2AEYT.html)

Comment: I am just using plain vanilla Spring Data JPA provided repository and the user query goes like this: `AppUser findByUseremailIgnoreCase(String useremail);`

Comment: So it's the AppUser declaration esp. the field with the @Temporal annotation - if any - and the DDL of the table that would be useful.

Comment: For brevity, I provided the link. If you click the ORACLE link in the first sentence it will show you the entire script. app_user table has M2M relationship with app_role app_department. Let me paste them here.

Comment: You map Date in Java with VARCHAR2 in SQL: bad idea.

Comment: You are right @p3consulting. That fixed it as it was trying to get one user and was not able to convert the string to timestamp format. Setting all dates to TIMESTAMP instead of string fixed it.  But still wondering how it worked just fine in MySQL. Thanks a lot for all your time and effort on this.

Comment: Probably because you get lucky with the default conversion format of TS and the locale in MySQL: back to my first comment... look at the SQL Office Hours session code...

Comment: Yes. That was helpful. I updated data type to TIMESTAMP for all related columns for MySQL and ORACLE both. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You map Date in Java with VARCHAR2 in SQL: bad idea. You probably get lucky with the default conversion format of TS and the locale in MySQL: back to my first comment... look at the SQL Office Hours session code...