# Unable to extract JDBC value for position `4`

Tags: java, spring

In the whole internet there is only two discussions about this problem where this one is usefull
[Spring Boot JPA error: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `7`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326450/spring-boot-jpa-error-unable-to-extract-jdbc-value-for-position-7)
and from this one i tryed everything and still get nothing
[Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152001/unable-to-extract-jdbc-value-for-position-3)
When i try to get all my measurements from db in json format, everything ruins to this error

```
2023-03-15T22:42:16.243+03:00 ERROR 952 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `4`] with root cause

I am own of hands rn. Is there a really good explanation to this problem

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : RainSensor
```

Here is my whole project

measurementDTO

```
public class MeasurementDTO {
    private float value;
    private boolean raining;
    @JsonBackReference
    private Sensor sensor;

    public MeasurementDTO()
    {

    }

    public MeasurementDTO(float value, boolean raining) {
        this.value = value;
        this.raining = raining;
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isRaining() {
        return raining;
    }

    public void setRaining(boolean raining) {
        this.raining = raining;
    }
    @JsonBackReference
    public Sensor getSensor() {
        return sensor;
    }

    public void setSensor(Sensor sensor) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
    }
```

measurement

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "measurement")
public class Measurement implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "value")
    private float value;

    @Column(name="raining")
    private boolean raining;
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="sensor")
    private Sensor sensor;

    @Column(name = "current")
    private LocalDateTime current;

    public Measurement() {

    }

    public Measurement(float value, boolean raining) {
        this.value = value;
        this.raining = raining;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCurrent() {return current;}

    public void setCurrent(LocalDateTime current) {this.current = current;}

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isRaining() {
        return raining;
    }

    public void setRaining(boolean raining) {
        this.raining = raining;
    }
    @JsonBackReference
    public Sensor getSensor() {
        return sensor;
    }

    public void setSensor(Sensor sensor) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

sensorDTO

```
public class SensorDTO {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Sensor's name can't be empty")
    @Size(min = 3,max = 250,message = "Amount of characters have to be between 3 and 250")
    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    public SensorDTO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public SensorDTO(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

sensor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sensor")
public class Sensor implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Sensor's name can't be empty")
    @Size(min = 3,max = 250,message = "Amount of characters have to be between 3 and 250")
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sensor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Measurement> measurements;


    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updated_at;

    public Sensor(){

    }
    public Sensor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Measurment Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/measurements")
public class MeasurementController {

    private final MeasurementService measurementService;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public MeasurementController(MeasurementService measurementService, ModelMapper modelMapper){
        this.measurementService = measurementService;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping
    private List<MeasurementDTO> getMeasurements(){
        return measurementService.getAllMeasurements().
                stream().
                map(this::convertToMeasurementDTO).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    @GetMapping("/{sensor}")
    private MeasurementDTO getMeasurement(@PathVariable String sensor){

        Measurement foundMeas = measurementService.getMeasurement(sensor);
        return convertToMeasurementDTO(foundMeas);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> addMeasurement(@RequestBody @Valid Measurement measurement,
                                                     BindingResult bindingResult){
        measurementService.addMeasurement(measurement);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private Measurement convertToMeasurement(MeasurementDTO measurementDTO){
        return modelMapper.map(measurementDTO, Measurement.class);
    }

    private MeasurementDTO convertToMeasurementDTO(Measurement measurement){
        return modelMapper.map(measurement, MeasurementDTO.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have default / no args constructors in your serializable classes, I wouldn't opt for serializing the entity but the column in the entity class instead.

You may find more about working with json types with spring in this article by Vlad https://vladmihalcea.com/java-map-json-jpa-hibernate/